# R code for zero inflated Poisson

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have used `glm()` to model some data I have. The code looks like the following:

```
for(ddm_idx in 1:90) {
    for(ppm_idx in 1:90) {
        mdfit <- glm(cuse[[4]] ~ cuse_ddm[[3 + ddm_idx]] + cuse_ddm[[3 + ddm_idx]]^2 + 
                                 cuse_ppm[[3 + ppm_idx]] + cuse_ppm[[3 + ppm_idx]]^2 + 
                                 cuse_ddm[[3 + ddm_idx]]*cuse_ppm[[3 + ppm_idx]], 
                     family=poisson(link=log))
        mdfit_dev[ddm_idx, ppm_idx] <- deviance(mdfit)
    }
}
```

It turns out that for each "case", I have about 90 different data points for `ddm` and `ppm` and so that's why I have the `for` loop run twice. I know this is correct because a post-doc in stats also ran the same in MATLAB and got the same results.

However, my next task to to use **zero inflated Poisson distribution** as I have a lot of zeros in my dataset. Some of these zeros are "true" zeros and some of them false.

How can I modify my code to use `glm()` for this distribution?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a false zero?

Comment: `cuse[[4]]` are the number of cases per week. There are 240 weeks. The number of cases are reported by someone. In some weeks there were indeed 0 cases. In other weeks, the person was too lazy to count or did not show up to work or forgot to count it for that week. This is a false zero.

Comment: Thanks. So both missing/`NA` and 0 are both coded as 0.

Comment: Yes, Correct. I wish i can send you some data but I unfortunately am under a contract. I think http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45262/zero-inflated-count-models-in-r-what-is-the-real-advantage is what I am looking for but I don't know what **regressors** are.

Comment: I'm likely glad you *can't*. (If it was too big to include in the question, I don't want it anyway; in many cases, it may be better to make up a small example that shows the essential features of what you're dealing with.)

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, I did update that comment. Would you know anything about regressors?

Comment: Do you know what [regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is? As in the first sentence [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Introduction_to_linear_regression)? In Poisson regression (and glms more generally), regressors (predictors, independent variables) play the same conceptual role as in multiple linear regression.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for code.

Comment: @gung Yes, this post does ask for code. But it also implicitly raises a question of how one could correctly handle mis-coded data in which true zeros are confounded with missing values. That question could only be answered here, not on SO, and a good answer would likely be much more useful than a pedestrian answer that points the OP to some blackbox code (which, if employed, would likely give bad results).

Comment: @whuber, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zeroinfl()` in the `pscl` package fits the zero-inflated Poisson regression model.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @pyoi. This isn't really an answer to the OP's question, it is more of a comment. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. I know it's frustrating, but you will be able to comment anywhere when your reputation >50. Alternatively, you could expand this to make it more of an answer. Since you are new here, you may want to take our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains information for new users.